# iframe scrollbar issues on iPad Safari Browser

Tags: browser, ipad, safari

Anyone here know the fix for this?

Comment: Greetings, you might want to tell us what the issue is.

Comment: hi tomdemuyt, the scrollbars are not visible on iframes. Also, users can't scrolldown within the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have stated that this is a feature and not a bug for safari on iPad - two finger scroll within the frame might do the trick for you?  However, would be nice to have some type of visual tip on scroll potential within the frame.

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=11612916

chad.

Comment: related issue (div's and iframe's) test page: http://www.webmanwalking.org/library/experiments/dsp_frames_outer_document.html